# Only allow plain text in aspx textbook

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I've got an aspx page that is allowing special formatting into a textbook (txtFeedback), so when the user copy and pastes a word document it carries the formatting over.

Is there anyway to strip rich text formatting on paste? Or force unformatted text only in the box?

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlReqFB" Visible="false">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidPeerNo" />  <br />
        <table>
            <tr><td>Email To</td><td colspan="5"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPeerEMail" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">EMail Text</td><td colspan="5"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPeerText" Height="100px" Width="250px" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFB" Visible="false" Text="Feedback"></asp:Label></td><td colspan="5"><asp:TextBox runat="server" Visible="false" ID="txtFeedback" Height="100px" Width="250px" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdSaveReq" OnClick="cmdSaveReq_Click" Text="Submit"></asp:Button></td><td></td></tr>

        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RegularExpressionValidator` for this. So something like

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z ]*$" ControlToValidate="txtFeedback" ErrorMessage="Your Error Message Text Here" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```